# Outlook 2010 install/activation issue

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I have an authentic Outlook 2010 with a Microsoft product key, but before that I used a evaluation version.

1. Now, when I open the Outlook application it tells me to insert the product key again; I try to enter my authentication key and it automatically begins the installation process again, as if I haven't installed it before.
2. Another problem is on the outlook's start-up screen, the new mail icon doesn't work well and I can't answer emails in this situation. Could someone help me?

Comment: Amigo, esse forum é apenas para ligua inglesa... Vou tentar traduzir pra voce mas as respostas que por ventura aconteçam vao ser em ingles...

Comment: The original question was posted on portuguese, I quickly translated it to english keeping it senses, If I make any gramatical mistakes please fell free to edit.

Comment: @DiogoRocha: You can also [link to the original question](http://superuser.com/revisions/395424/1).

Answer (score 2):

I have seen this and the only thing that seemed to work was a complete uninstall and resinstall. In one case, it would not uninstall from Control Panel so it took a bit more.

MS has some help [Office Uninstall](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290301)

Comment: Translating the answear to @lui: Eu já tive esse tipo de problema e a única opção que pareceu resolver o problema foi uma completa desinstalação e uma nova instalação. Em determinada situação não foi possível desinstalar pelo Painel de Controle e foi um pouco mais complicado. Voce pode encontrar mais informações no link da resposta acima.